# Do not remove characters from path name C#

Tags: c#, string, command-line-arguments

I have a Windows Form Application that takes a command line argument as well. You can run the program by itself it has a GUI but when you run it in CLI it seems like C# removes some characters from my argument that I feed it.

This is how it works:

> RemoveHTML.exe http://illen/configtc.aspx?IP=192.168.0.15&m=c

The app loads but crashes because C# removed the last part of the the URL! So what it's really seeing is

> RemoveHTML.exe http://illen/configtc.aspx?IP=192.168.0.15

It removes the "&m=c" part and in my CLI I get this error:

```
C:\Users\admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RemoveHTML\RemoveHTML\bin\Debug>RemoveHTML.exe http://illen/configtc.aspx?IP=192.168.0.15 
'm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

My code is located in the Form1_Load section and it is:

```
string MyURL;
string[] WebURL;
```

......

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {

                WebURL[0] = args[1];
                //WebURL[0] += "&m=c";
                //WebURL[0] += (WebURL[0] + "&m=c");
                //WebURL = args[1];
                //MessageBox.Show(WebURL);
                runtimeButton_Click(sender, e);
            }
}
```

I am trying to find a way to not have C# remove the illegal characters, any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

When calling your application, put the URL in quotes.

```
RemoveHTML.exe "http://illen/configtc.aspx?IP=192.168.0.15&m=c"
```

Its not a limitation of .NET or C#. Its the way the command parser works.

Comment: +1. Ampersand is command separator for CMD (it allows to run several commands one after another). Check out CMD/? for complete list of characters that makes you to put quotes around the arguments.